# Forcing including lib from local repo into JAR with Spring thin layout

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm using [spring thin layout](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher). All runs fine up to the point that I use a local maven project in the thin layout project.

On building, this lib isn't going into the thin JAR and the lib isn't available from a public maven repository.

Is there any way to force a lib to going into the thin JAR ?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mywork</groupId>
        <artifactId>my_api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency> 
 ...
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: If I correctly understand the thin-layout is for Spring Plugins but not for Spring Boot in general ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't know if I get you: I have a Spring Boot app and all runs fine with thin deployment, except, that `my_api.jar` isn´t in the thin JAR nor in a public respository. So, on deploying it does not find `my_api.jar` and I was asking is it possible to add `my_api.jar` to the thin JAR with *maven*.

Comment: Ok lets go different direction..have you installed the `my_api` somehow ? Via Maven ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, after build it is in my local maven repository.

Comment: I assume the version you are using in the given pom `${project.version}` seemed to be wrong cause I assume the `my_api` has a different versions?

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok, i changed this in the Q. But it makes no difference. `my_api` isn't still included into the thin JAR. For now I will go with `--thin.dryrun` and deploy the repo on changes.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this requirement (a local library that I want included in my "thin" jar) the public dependancies to work as expected with Thin Laucher.

It looks like it is currently not available, but the feature has been requested:

https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher/issues/15

As a work around, I have been manually copying the respective custom/non public JARs into the local maven repo folder created by Thin Launcher.

Comment: The workaround provided works , but the issue is open even in the 1.0.14.RELEASE (at the time of writing the comment)